# Quotes within Quotes, Google API JSON + PYTHON + POSTGREDB

Tags: python, json, postgresql

I have been unable to handle quotes within quotes returned in JSON file. 
Python does one thing to handle it and the postgredb does another. 
I am all confused on how to handle it.

To be straight to the point, I get a json from google API which is here:

```
    {
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "Mt Cook National Park",
            "short_name" : "Mt Cook National Park",
            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Canterbury",
            "short_name" : "Canterbury",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "New Zealand",
            "short_name" : "NZ",
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "7999",
            "short_name" : "7999",
            "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
         }
      ],
      "adr_address" : "\u003cspan class=\"locality\"\u003eMt Cook National Park\u003c/span\u003e \u003cspan class=\"postal-code\"\u003e7999\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"country-name\"\u003eNew Zealand\u003c/span\u003e",
      "formatted_address" : "Mt Cook National Park 7999, New Zealand",
      "formatted_phone_number" : "03-435 1653",
      "geometry" : {
         "location" : {
            "lat" : -43.7364999,
            "lng" : 170.0989493
         },
         "viewport" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : -43.7351509197085,
               "lng" : 170.1002982802915
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : -43.7378488802915,
               "lng" : 170.0976003197085
            }
         }
      },
      "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/lodging-71.png",
      "id" : "dfed4d694ea89bf6be3a352b159623d917f421c1",
      "international_phone_number" : "+64 3-435 1653",
      "name" : "Mt Cook Lodge and Motel",
      "photos" : [
         {
            "height" : 540,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/108050286121550519618/photos\"\u003eEllie Choi\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAnzfg-U-7RdqayAqJB2Fru84CYNXdRQ6EmZKiBdOseZV4I3N05XO7Ehux5vp84CIegydHW0eQE1SDhlcDrBbQJM6yc-1ToMB1FCkaTqHoj6Xmka0kiRz0FjQx2TOnZf7-EhAff-lv4yV9JEWTcCEqwubyGhTBlQaxP_lqdyMQ1HsnVPKX5A90JA",
            "width" : 960
         },
         {
            "height" : 4032,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110549331727067931089/photos\"\u003eMelody Li\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAA1v5WhvZx_Qjg1SFZfwR2u-jafIrCzTMWCbbiqyfX7NUiKbGPKoY0mfrYd2fQNaBzKviCTV8TEePR4vsxJQIrJ5Kvijoa4ge8Jh4morCY8XJHd3X-wZuO1qHuNs4nBl7GEhBjty3FshioZu8GsanNjKsSGhR4faq9OU5vcJ0H5vZO8C3uiXtnqA",
            "width" : 3024
         },
         {
            "height" : 2976,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/113295503239818946682/photos\"\u003eJeff\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAA3VCpf87699o02e-3O-59OyzWziMzEErYFDkEq_MONJjvPGYNeP6J6xQT0tfgapb-MJ_JQsYJYslh4A2yTEji5sGL-bOnR1Ghm3ivNIWUOGnVxaA1UgMR8wGC_ddUBvJqEhADVV97qhpuC3ApEnCgKxk4GhTR10JOl-7tb4sKOVHYYLl79ON2LQ",
            "width" : 3968
         },
         {
            "height" : 1080,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100722193417268901357/photos\"\u003eSu Min\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAfmUSawjs6dNubeazeo_wmadsyLNcJRogJ69STVEZquXsxY2sIDfHmtxLUqEodkqRYSPGWDX7fI-OYjrPDe0MzdnJzHJSAt7mcf1UyfHq_dZb9-teqFyqOEdeQ2z3xCDLEhDpxJwlv7D94YOCl82jwfjDGhR6XpAZnF-RwTUf1ToBE8tjGCHUAw",
            "width" : 1616
         },
         {
            "height" : 2960,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/113295503239818946682/photos\"\u003eJeff\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAkWyfCqRvpb5zg07Rzy0GqL5MHQDw2i-HMdEzqw51FshZimYVx7kWmCt-bztMEuECOJkgrspQCJlSml9pcbo7nXDTI9i_7WwfMmybRzXHRmm8vYXQOFK593DiBBuj3tJUEhB1CGdwtNb2sGB7d0QYc5ntGhSPo8WBB2BBeWVSd8UHK8r2a1m_TQ",
            "width" : 3952
         },
         {
            "height" : 960,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/103513026764128366369/photos\"\u003eJack Lee\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAA8HqhkhHDchBhC-SvhzcwqL1aJEPs-ERft3Lw2_AQzOTngUGdyLBTurZmNcbIiJTxq9I0cSL7zZNqiwE7oBcgBMDAB5dFAE4ZQYn70Y7MlU1dta4_woEjmauqn3vRbSnyEhDuXEkf_oyBecsOEoAbBK_GGhScBrrUA10VR3AkP_9iI3q2HeTxog",
            "width" : 1706
         },
         {
            "height" : 2976,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/113295503239818946682/photos\"\u003eJeff\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAA7kNP6NMYhu2rAfZrmiMdWRZam_vz7p6hRljjaOVx_Dl8x5_lNBQHjE2tsysy72si8QZTFhZCg9VRQF-wcY_yUNEPezFbHhWnn2w6AJEQatbWtnhE6MiNoWHFjMwb6FBDEhAMjtxgbxPgZieonI5VXJg2GhSY_xhiQPkpY8d6dH772zJCMG1hrw",
            "width" : 3968
         },
         {
            "height" : 3096,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/112415917350560216557/photos\"\u003eAndrew Robb\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAARh4IVX8cuCPiHnsaGFj6VRkaoC2tSFRO-kntjDPW0uXA5YKHF0EKL1HyaN5G0pY1PPzXnnhYsqrotT2U93LgClKqKcMfwWmJxA4nombgHSdOUg7gUuAzHkD8GQYgIi-UEhCkxq7NXJ9VQ5lD6PfSOXRKGhSuzLznpizGWDM6MGaZhJXeEhz1HA",
            "width" : 4128
         },
         {
            "height" : 2268,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/101293002368238749006/photos\"\u003eCorne van der Westhuizen\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAZFkPm4g055jTlt0edO-0LBZOrsh1YTh6XzuM4aJxC8o6IdhVYgDff7PYoSuZ8Pue_KCgqLq_5PVKpYiL2Ihkp0z8qBp7luwNSnmZdv3PaTQ1V7Ew2QpsLA-f9rDTPW1cEhDlwvQvrstsCgsmDd8Z-2QNGhQN_t0rCa-y-4h0ZV5Hc9JuGuF1eQ",
            "width" : 4032
         },
         {
            "height" : 1360,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110170972772792272403/photos\"\u003e高橋和也\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAncS_1e2Pr8rPvDvMfsGc1T1i5cqdQUK3bBuZiEQ1rMd5S825xoN21WNhoZLk1544AC6euQq8oA48PcO7CrOiFTEnyewA_2T9gDHV77cRCLEGBuLlWDgp2529x3-xMhGUEhA8WIpZeFLDtcN-AarJvz2IGhQBZ5dgK31_auxdKcjlaX3zPUaI0Q",
            "width" : 2048
         }
      ],
      "place_id" : "ChIJ2fi5GK20K20Rv2BtDceLwIY",
      "rating" : 3.8,
      "reference" : "CmRSAAAA5BDF1myqhU3mXivOmf13NWZWXsm1TmXlSmqzw9ofaheM8R-NqzG9TJs0ByXsInspupJpj4X7K0pFV83ZZGVVIMuGhg1PLZQQnxVVAHw9DjiOau4ZIY4SPk_ZbcrSPTlGEhAlNyhhsBaVdyRjkqniY89aGhTD2Kor8gIsnFzk-ud25EXMPfSwOw",
      "reviews" : [
         {
            "author_name" : "Kim-Yen Nguyen",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/107238835762969885704/reviews",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-z9PWZ-QoJxQ/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABG0/wNOHWLI6P68/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba2/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 4,
            "relative_time_description" : "2 weeks ago",
            "text" : "We loved the stay at the motel room, which was spacious, clean, we even had a back yard. // Then the stay at the lodge was only so so, cleanliness could have been better, the general state of the bathroom was not superb. Overall satisfied with Mt Cook Lodge and Motel, but would definitely recommend staying at a motel room if budget allows.",
            "time" : 1514865875
         },
         {
            "author_name" : "Ben Lilburne",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/109755001469843583867/reviews",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-HdZVXck6Kek/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABQ/v1vfaukWe5o/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 5,
            "relative_time_description" : "a month ago",
            "text" : "Had a motel room at the bottom of the hill, it's a beautiful area, but is very busy at times as tour buses come through. The rooms are spacious and quiet, great views from anywhere here. It's a short walk up the hill on a gravel path to the main place where tours go from.",
            "time" : 1511721269
         },
         {
            "author_name" : "Lucas Jewett",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/110030254920960945419/reviews",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-I7Ps4CSwGnU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AA6ZPT5LvSLYc7_r9mkmF96YB9hG7LVzGg/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 4,
            "relative_time_description" : "a month ago",
            "text" : "Great rooms. No AC just window's. The couch was a fold out bed as well. You can easily hear people above you walking around as well.",
            "time" : 1511892349
         },
         {
            "author_name" : "Nicholas Poh",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/117169519963119381503/reviews",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-IQzeAxgoa4Y/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAACAJg/QusM_WIUXrQ/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 4,
            "relative_time_description" : "2 weeks ago",
            "text" : "Room was good. Restaurant's view is awesome. There's a communal kitchen for guest use.",
            "time" : 1515125180
         },
         {
            "author_name" : "Curtis Mohrhardt",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/105675185047970962389/reviews",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-E8RLgnnD15g/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAC0/kJZ1Z9BLmx8/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 5,
            "relative_time_description" : "3 weeks ago",
            "text" : "We were put in one of the newer cabins, it was very clean and enough room for a family of four. Short drive to the hiking trails. Great place.",
            "time" : 1514529120
         }
      ],
      "scope" : "GOOGLE",
      "types" : [ "lodging", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
      "url" : "https://maps.google.com/?cid=9709914483650814143",
      "utc_offset" : 780,
      "vicinity" : "Mt Cook National Park",
      "website" : "http://mtcooklodge.co.nz/"
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Now the problem is that I want this to go straight into the a column of my POSTGREDB in JSON format. POSTGREDB handles JSON pretty decently.

What I tried to do is is escape the single quote which comes within this API...

But that means that the POSTGREDB pops up errors.

I am going mad. I tried the following:

```
URL='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid='+rows[0]+'&key=Something something'
    file = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
    file1=file.read()
    file2=json.loads(file1)
    file3=json.dumps(file2)
    query='update public.attraction set g_json_1=\'%s\' where google_place_id="%s"'% (file3,str(rows[0]))
    print(query)
    cursor.execute(query)
```

Comment: try: `query="update public.attraction set g_json_1='%s' where google_place_id=%s"% (file3,str(rows[0]))` also post your error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that in Postgres, you can escape single quotes `'` by doubling it `''`

So you may need to replace `'` by `''` in your json content

```
URL='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid='+rows[0]+'&key=Something something'
file = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
file1=file.read()
file2=json.loads(file1)
file3=json.dumps(file2)
file3 = file3.replace("'", "''")  # escape single quotes
query='update public.attraction set g_json_1=\'%s\' where google_place_id="%s"'% (file3,str(rows[0]))
print(query)
cursor.execute(query)
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Awesome. Worked perfectly. 

What I was doing was doing one of the two. Either i was escaping the ' of the python or of postgresql. Not both. 
I tried both once but that was just after file1 stage.